# TP4056 power sharing circuit Rpull

Tags: power, schottky, tp4056

I am replicating the TP4056 charging circuit on https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/tp4056-page2.html and solving the power-sharing problem. The website mentions a Rpull resistor that pulls down the diode but doesn't explain what values to use.

Does anyone have any experience with this? What value of Rpull should be used?

[image]

Comment: Can you simulate a good value? Can you do some mental ranging, like would 1 to 100 ohms sound good, or 1k to 100k, or 1 Mohm to 100 Mohm? Then the next question is, does it really matter much which exact value it is, as long as it is not too low or too high?

Comment: I'd guess that it depends mostly on the reverse-leakage current spec of whatever diode you use for D1. Rpull needs to be low enough that it can sink that amount of current and the Rpull/Q1gate/D1anode net stays low enough to keep Q1 properly turned on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are a new contributor: Read Microchips application note AN1149 that is referenced in the link you provided. If you haven't read them before, application notes are like fun datasheets. ;)

[image]

Comment: Oh wow thanks @Dejvid_no1! Didn't know these existed.